# Help with XML response from PHP

Tags: php, iphone, xml, curl, simplexml

I am new to PHP, and I am using it to POST data from an iPhone. I have written a basic code to get data from the iPhone, post it to the php script on my server, and then using PHP, send that data to another webserver. However, the webserver is returning a response in XML, and since I am a newbie to PHP, I need help with it.
My code to send data:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://api.online-convert.com/queue-insert");
$count = $_POST['count'];

$request["queue"] = file_get_contents($count);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

I know I need to parse the XML response, but I have no idea how to do that. The XML response would be something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<queue-answer>
  <status>
    <code>0</code>
    <message>Successfully inserted job into queue.</message>
  </status>
  <params>
    <downloadUrl>http://www.online-convert.com/result/07d6c1491bb5929acd71c531122d2906</downloadUrl>
    <hash>07d6c1491bb5929acd71c531122d2906</hash>
  </params>
</queue-answer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

#### SimpleXML

To load data from a string into an object: [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

#### DOMDocument

To create one from a string: [`DOMDocument->loadXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php).

Comment: wouldn't domdocument be overkill for parsing xml in this situation?

Comment: @romaninsh: Why would it be overkill? It's certainly an option.

Comment: okay. great looking answer now. Show difference, Let OP decide. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Read about SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0):

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+parse+xml)!

The built-in [PHP XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) is your best bet.

Comment: does this work for a XML response? because i first have to send data to the server using PHP, then I receive the response

Comment: The response will be a string, correct? Then you feed the string to the parser or, as romaninsh suggests, [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (which is very nice).